# How to translate one language to another using jQuery

Tags: jquery, translation

I am using jquery.translate-1.3.4.min.js and jquery-1.2.6.min.js for language translation.
By using the above files I can translate only Hindi and foreign languages, but I want South Indian languages.

Answer (score 1):

As stated on its [Google Code page](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-translate/), the plugin simply integrates the Google Translate API into jQuery. If Google Translate doesn't happen to have the language you need, then there really isn't a lot you can do about it.

However, I would advise you to update to the latest version of the plugin, as the version you're using is very old.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try: http://www.superawesomejquery.com/plugins/2_jquery-google-translate-plugin/